# What is the probability that this quadratic equation has real roots?

Tags: calculus, probability

(I've seen the other questions in this site similar to my problem, but they didn't help much). So, the problem is:

> The numbers $B$ and $C$ are chosen at random between $−1$ and $1$,
>   independently of each other. What is the probability that the
>   quadratic equation $x^2+Bx+C=0$ has real roots?

I've actually gotten an answer, but it's wrong according to my book. Here's what I did: I know that the condition for that equation to have real roots is that $B^2-4C\ge 0\Rightarrow C\le\frac{B^2}{4}$. The sample space consists of all points $(x,y):-1\le x\le1,-1\le y\le1$. So I think the desired probability should be the ratio of the area a square of side-lenght $2$ to the area under $C\le\frac{B^2}{4}$ from $-1$ to $1$.

That makes intuitive sense to me, but the book says the answer is actually $\frac{1}{4}(2+\int_{-1}^{1}x^2dx)$. Where does that $2$ come from? Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Hint: Draw a graph of the region you describe and see if it matches the area you wrote down.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the discriminant is always non negative if $C\leq 0$. You forgot the area under the $x$- respectively $B$-axis.

Comment: Thanks. If you allow me one more question regarding the same problem: the book also asks for a formula for the probability in the general case where $B$ and $C$ are chosen at random from the interval $(−q, q)$ for
any $q > 0$. Using the same logic as before and after some simplification, I've found the expression $1/2+q/24$. However, according to the manual solution, this expression is only valid for $0<q<4$. For $q\ge 4$, the probability is given by $1-2/3\sqrt{q}$. Could you help me understand why we need a different formula for $q\ge 4$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following link may help you: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758675/the-probability-that-the-quadratic-equation-has-real-roots

Answer (score 1):

The answer must be: $\frac{1}{4}(2+\color{red}{\frac14}\int_{-1}^{1}x^2dx)$.

Refer to the graph:

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

The required probability is the ratio of the green area to the total area:
$$\frac{2+\int_{-1}^1 \frac{B^2}{4}dB}{4}=\frac14\left(2+\frac14\int_{-1}^1 B^2dB\right)=\frac{13}{24}.$$

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the answer given in the book is exactly correct or not. Because I am finding a different answer while I tried to compute the probability.

***What I attempted:-***  The numbers $B$ and $C$ are chosen randomly from $[-1,1]$. So, we can model them as  uniform random variables taking values between $-1$ and $1$. If $b$ and $c$ denote the values taken by the random variables $B$ and $C$ respectively, then \begin{equation}  f_B(b)=\frac{1}{1-\left( -1\right)}=\frac{1}{2} \qquad -1\le b \le 1 
\end{equation}  and,\begin{equation}  f_C(c)=\frac{1}{1-\left( -1\right)}=\frac{1}{2} \qquad -1\le c \le 1  
\end{equation}

As you have already mentioned, for real roots we must have $C\le \frac{B^2}{4}$. So, the only constraint is imposed upon $C$ and its value should be less than$\frac{B^2}{4} $. $B$ is free to vary in the range $(-1,1)$. So, the required probability is given by 
\begin{equation} 
\begin{aligned} 
P\left(C\le \frac{B^2}{4}\right) &=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{\frac{b^2}{4}} f_{BC}(b,c) dc db \\
&=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{\frac{b^2}{4}} f_B(b).f_C(c) dc db \qquad\mbox{(Since $B$ and $C$ are independent)}  \\
&=\int_{-1}^{1} \int_{-1}^{\frac{b^2}{4}} \frac{1}{4} dc db  \\
&=\frac{1}{4} \left(\int_{-1}^{1}\left(\frac{b^2}{4}+1 \right)db \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{4}\times \frac{2}{3} +2\right) \\
&=\frac{13}{24} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I think you missed the factor $\frac{1}{4}$ just before the integral inside the parentheses. As you mentioned in the comment, there is a general formula when $B$ and $C$ lie in an interval $\left[-n,n\right]$. So, if you put $n=1$, the required probability is $=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24}=\frac{13}{24}$