# The probability that the quadratic equation has real roots

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have this problem on which I would appreciate some help.

> "Consider the quadratic equation $x^2 + Bx + C = 0$ where $B$ and $C$
>   are independent and are uniformly distributed on $[-n,n]$. Find the
>   probability that the equation has real roots. What happens as $n
> > \longrightarrow \infty $?"

So, my attempt goes like this.

First note that since their uniformly distributed on $[-n,n]$ we know that $f_B(x) = 1/2n$ and $F_C = \frac{x+n}{2n}$.

Obviously, we are looking for $P(C\leqq(B/2)^2)$.

Now, if we condition on $B=x$ we can use the law of total probability

$P(C\leqq(B/2)^2)=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(C\leqq(B/2)^2 | B=x)f_B(x)dx=\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(C\leqq(x/2)^2 | B=x)f_B(x)dx$

which is equal to

$\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} P(C\leqq(x/2)^2)f_B(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_C((x/2)^2)f_B(x)dx$

because of their independence.

Thus,

$P(C\leqq(B/2)^2) = \frac{1}{4n^2}\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\frac{x}{2})^2 + n dx$

and because we know that $x \in [-n,n]$ we get

$P(C\leqq(B/2)^2) = \frac{1}{4n^2}\displaystyle \int_{-n}^{n} (\frac{x}{2})^2 + n dx$

which evaluates to

$\frac{n}{24} + \frac{1}{2}$.

However, my text book says that the right answer is $\frac{n}{24} + \frac{1}{2}$ for $n\leqq 4$ and $1-2/(3\sqrt{n})$ for $n \geqq 4$. What am I doing wrong in my solution above? Clearly I must do something right, because I get partially the right answer.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be aware that: $$F_C(x)=\frac{x+n}{2n}\tag1$$ is true for $x\in[-n,n]$ but not for values outside this interval.

If $0<n\leq 4$ then $|b|\leq n$ implies that also $0\leq\frac14b^2\leq n$ so that you can make use of $(1)$ without meeting troubles.

This however is not the case when $n>4$. If e.g. $n=10$ then $\frac14b^2$ takes values in $[0,25]$ and $(1)$ will not be valid for $10<x\leq25$.

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I still struggle however, how to evaluate the integral. So, we know that $(x/2)^2 < n \implies x < 2\sqrt{n}$. How did you directly see that $n=4 $ is the maximum value on $n$ for which $|x|\ in [-n,n]$ ? And how does $F_C$ look outside this interval?

Comment: I saw it "directly" because you mentioned that value in your question. If not then I would have found it on base of equality  $n=n^2/4$. If $x>n$ then $F_C(x)=1$ and if $x<-n$ then $F_C (x)=0$.