# Find the probability that the equation has real roots.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider the quadratic equation $x^2 + Bx + C = 0$ where $B$ and $C$
>   are independent and have uniform distributions on $[−n, n]$. Find the
>   probability that the equation has real roots.

I know that $x\in\mathbb{R}$ iff $B^2/4\ge C.$I'm looking for $P(B^2/4\ge C).$ So basically, I need to draw the region $C\leq B^2/4$ and compute the area. The area inside of the square $[-n,n]\times[-n,n]$ and below the function is given by

$$A_N=\int_{-n}^{n}\frac{B^2}{4} \ dB + 2n^2= \frac{n^3}{6}+2n^2,$$

and the total area of the square is $A_T=(2n)^2=4n^2$ so

$$P(B^2/4 \geq C)=\frac{A_N}{A_T}=\frac{\frac{n^3}{6}+2n^2}{4n^2}=\frac{n}{24}+\frac{1}{2}.$$

The answer is $1/2+n/24$ for $n\le4$ and $1-2/(3\sqrt{n})$ for $n\ge 4.$

Why does one need to splitt it into cases like this?

**EDIT:**

I Editet my question since I figured out the first part of my problem. The question above remains.

Comment: Note that your answer is $>1$ when $n>12$. This is not possible

Comment: Draw a picture for say n=1 and n=5 and shade the region of the event.

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo - Ok so then the point at which the answer should change should be 12 and not 4?

Comment: @Batman, I did. Only thing that happened was that the region increased in size.

Comment: @Parseval no. My point was that your answer is not valid. The problem is that the parabola can intercept the vertical sides of the square ($n\leq 4$) or the horizontal (up) side of the square ($n>4$)

Comment: @Parseval and then the integral $\int_{-n}^n$ is wrong

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo - Ok I understand why things change when $n\geq 4.$ But How would I arrive at the correct answer by setting upp a proper integral?

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo - I suppose it just comes with drawing and looking att the figure for different values of $n$. But then my integral is correct if $n\leq 4$. I suppose I just have to set up 2 different integrals then.

Comment: Yes, you have 2 cases. When $n>4$ consider the values of $x$ such that $x^2/4=n$ (ie, the intersections of parabola with the horizontal side). The area will be $\int_{x_1}^{x_2}x^2/4dx$ + 2 area rectangule (with sides $n$ and $n-x_i$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo - Yes I got it. for $n\geq4$ the answer becomes $$\int_{-2\sqrt{n}}^{2\sqrt{n}}\frac{B^2}{4} \ dB+2n\cdot (n-2\sqrt{n})+2n^2=1-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{n}}.$$

Comment: Similar [_Q&A_](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607395/probability-that-a-quadratic-equation-with-random-coefficients-has-real-roots)

Comment: Same question asked a few days back:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2758675/the-probability-that-the-quadratic-equation-has-real-roots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Hereafter I'll use
>   [Iverson Bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket) which is a *convenient* 'tool' to handle constraints. Namely, $\ds{\bracks{P}}$ is equal to $\ds{\color{red}{ONE}}$ whenever $\ds{P}$ *proposition* is $\ds{\large\texttt{true}}$ and $\ds{\color{red}{ZERO}}$ otherwise.

\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\ds{{1 \over 2n}\int_{-n}^{n}{1 \over 2n}
\int_{-n}^{n}\bracks{B^{2} - 4C \geq 0}\dd B\,\dd C}} =
{1 \over 2n^{2}}\int_{0}^{n}
\int_{-n}^{n}\bracks{C \leq {B^{2} \over 4}}\dd C\,\dd B
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2n^{2}}\int_{0}^{n}
\int_{0}^{n}\braces{\bracks{C \leq {B^{2} \over 4}} +
\bracks{-C \leq {B^{2} \over 4}}}\dd C\,\dd B
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2n^{2}}\int_{0}^{n}
\braces{\bracks{{B^{2} \over 4} < n}\int_{0}^{B^{2}/4}\dd C +
\bracks{{B^{2} \over 4} \geq n}\int_{0}^{n}\dd C + n}\dd B
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2n^{2}}\int_{0}^{n}
\braces{\bracks{B < 2\root{n}}{B^{2} \over 4} +
\bracks{B \geq 2\root{n}}n}\dd B + {1 \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 8n^{2}}\int_{0}^{n}\bracks{B < 2\root{n}}B^{2}\,\dd B +
{1 \over 2n}\int_{0}^{n}\bracks{B \geq 2\root{n}}\,\dd B + {1 \over 2}
\\[1cm] & =
{\bracks{2\root{n} \leq n} \over 8n^{2}}\int_{0}^{2\root{n}}B^{2}\,\dd B +
{\bracks{2\root{n}  > n} \over 8n^{2}}\int_{0}^{n}B^{2}\,\dd B
\\[2mm] &
+ {\bracks{2\root{n} \leq n} \over 2n}\int_{2\root{n}}^{n}\,\dd B + {1 \over 2}
\\[1cm] & =
{\bracks{n \geq 4} \over 3\root{n}} + \bracks{n < 4}\,{n \over 24} +
\bracks{n \geq 4}\,{n - 2\root{n} \over 2n} + {1 \over 2}
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2} + \bracks{n < 4}{n \over 24} + \bracks{n \geq 4}\pars{{1 \over 2} -
{2 \over 3\root{n}}}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\bracks{n < 4}\pars{{1 \over 2} + {n \over 24}} +
\bracks{n \geq 4}\pars{1 - {2 \over 3\root{n}}}}
\end{align}

[image]

Comment: I seriously have no idea how you can do calculations with those inequalities in the square brackets, but I'm giving you the accepted answer since you took the time writing this.

Comment: @Parseval Thanks. $\displaystyle\left[\cdots\right]$ is an $\texttt{Iverson Bracket}$. I just added a brief explanation at the answer top.